# OnPrem Exchange to Office 365 Migration

Tags: office365, exchange, migration

Current Scenario: We have an onprem Exchange with 10 users, used Azure AD Connect to Sync users to Cloud for using Exchange Online Protection & ATP.

But now we are planning to migrate all users to Office 365 using cutover migration.

Now, I'm not sure if the cutover migration will try to recreate the accounts and fail or if it will just migrate in the already existing accounts with the correct mail address.

Any help or recommendation is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Same question?
https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2276528-onprem-exchange-to-office-365-migration?from_forum=33

As I mentioned, It uses the address book on your on-premises Exchange server to identify the mailboxes, distribution groups, and contacts that will be migrated to your Office 365 organization and provisions new Exchange Online mailboxes.

So if the AD accounts are already synced to Exchange Online, you will get error when perform cutover migration I think.